# Where is appletouch.c stored in lubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, 64-bit, touchpad, macbook

I upgraded my lubuntu 14.04 32 bit to a 64 bit version, so needed to reinstall the drivers. When trying to make the touchpad work, I changed the synaptic's file as answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/467741) and wanted to change the appletouch file as mentioned [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813884&page=6). I can't seem to find the appletouch.c file though.

```
user@MacBook:~$ sudo find / -type f -name "appletouch.*"
/lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/appletouch.ko
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic/include/config/mouse/appletouch.h
```

The header file is empty and the ko-file is an executable file, so can't seem to change much to these files. So anybody know where I could find the appletouch.c file and why it isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appletouch.c` is included in the kernel source code (under `drivers/input/mouse`).

You can view it online using the Ubuntu kernel git repo [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-trusty.git;a=blob;f=drivers/input/mouse/appletouch.c;h=e42f1fa8cdc075c1bed3094de041563fb8d2af88;hb=HEAD).
To modify `appletouch.c` you'll have to recompile the 14.04 kernel (or at least this kernel module).

To get the 14.04 kernel source, you can use this command: `apt-get source linux-source-3.13.0`

Comment: Hmm I dont remember doing that last time. Thanks for the fast reply though!

Comment: @PeterRaeves This [comment](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813884&page=6&p=11973897#post11973897) seems to provide a way to just compile `appletouch.c`

Comment: It worked ! ^_^